# Parsing AMR-WB Codec bitstream

Tags: parsing, codec, speech, amr

I am using the amr-wb+ codec provided by 3gpp.

On one of the websites for documentation, they were explaining how the raw bitsream file is parsed

http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.290/26290-c00.zip

And this document which I'm looking through now tries to explain how the LPC voice parameters are converted to immitance spectral pairs and then vector quantized.
http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.190/26190-c00.zip

I only want to examine the parameters that the codec produces in the bistream and given the format, I'm able to do that.  However, what I am unsure about is that after i get the various bits for the different LPC parameters, I'm not sure how to convert them into real numbers.  I'm not sure what format these bits are stored in.  All I know is that tehy were vector quantized, but I don't know anything else to convert these bits into actual numbers.  Any help would be appreciated if anyone has such experience with codecs.

Answer (score 0):

The data processing pipeline in such codecs is pretty complex with lots of special handling of various parameters. It is better to download the existing source code for the codec and modify it instead according to your needs. You can download code here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/opencore-amr/

You are interested in `pvDecoder_AmrWb` function in `pvamrwbdecoder.cpp` file